# Camera Interfacing with Opencv:

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have Windows 8 on "DELL Inspiron 5537" installed and i create a virtual machine from "Virtual box" and installed Ubuntu 13.04 in it. And then I installed Opencv Version=2.4.9 through commands in Ubuntu's terminal now I want to do camera interfacing in opencv which is very necessary for my project to move forward..my code contains no error still it is not working the way i want.
My code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;
char key;
int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);    //Create window
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);  
//Capture using any camera connected to your system
    while(1){ //Create infinte loop for live streaming
        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image 
frames from capture
        cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);   //Show image 
frames on created window
        key = cvWaitKey(10);     //Capture Keyboard stroke
        if (char(key) == 27){
        //cvSaveImage("webcam_frame.png",frame);
        }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this code in my terminal it is not capturing the image rather it shows a blank window. I have attached a photo of output of this code.

Comment: Do you have any console logs/errors from opencv ? Also try running `cheese` and check if the camera is working

Comment: can you please tell me what is "cheese" and we have no logs/error in opencv

Comment: `cheese` is an application you can install on Ubuntu (or is installed by default), it uses camera, to take photos ect. You can check if the camera is working in the system.

Comment: Most probably your virtual machine is not properly configured to use the built in web cam.